# How to make the UWP app compatible with every target version

Tags: c#, uwp

I have created the custom controls. I have did the code changes to fix the issue in the AppWindow by setting the XamlRoot. But what's my problem is XamlRoot is available only in latest version.

So I changed the source target version to the latest version. When I create the UWP app with the same version of custom control, it works fine. But when the UWP project version has a lower target version (which doesn't support XamlRoot), I have got an exception:

> Method Not Found

I have checked the conditions to execute the XamlRoot code only when targetversion is higher. But it does not work. I have tried with `ApiInformation`, but it is also of no use, since this is only to make the UWP app compatible for every device and not depends on the App TargetVersion.

Please refer the below code which I uses to fix the issue in the popUp

```
popUp.XamlRoot = this.CustomControl.XamlRoot
```

I have set the xamlroot of the customcontrol to the popup's XamlRoot. So now the popup will be opened in the customcontrol.

Please refer the github link.

https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4676

Is there any way to fix this ?

Comment: Does my reply explains your issue?

Comment: yes, thank you for your words,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [XamlRoot class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.xamlroot?view=winrt-19041), it requires Windows 10, version 1903 or higher. You could not find this object in the lower version of UWP. You have to set the min version as 1903 to avoid compile issue.